# How to call sql function from mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I need to call sql function from mule, i need to know the syntax be declared as part of query key

sample sql script:

```
create or replace type testArray  as table of varchar2(30);

create or replace function getTestArray return testArray   as 

  t_data testArray := testArray();   begin

   for i in 1 .. 10 loop
       t_data.extend;
       t_data(t_data.count) := 'entry ' ||  i;
   end loop;
   return t_data;
end;
```

i need to call getTestArray function.Please let me know how i need to declare mule query key to call function.

Comment: Can you share your Mule config?

Answer (score 0):

Both the legacy JDBC transport and the new DB connector support calling stored procedures:

- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JDBC+Transport+Reference#JDBCTransportReference-OutboundStoredProcedureSupport-Basic
- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector